# Role of Request and Response object

Tags: asp.net

I am building a web page for creating an account for new user,
as user fill all the "Must" information, he/she clicks on create button, after submitting the values, page will be posted back to itself.
Do I need to add some cookie into the Request object and fetch it from Response object to check whether the Creations was successful or not and I can display a success message.

or by which mean I can display a creation success message on the same page.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: you probably ought to read a book or two on web development and ASP.NET - these are real fundamentals which every programmer should know how to solve trivially before embarking on any project

Answer (score 0):

Which technology you are working on. In ASP/ASP.net, you can simply write as

```
Response.Write("Your Message");
```

Comment: I am working on ASP.NET, Response.Write will write the message on the top of the page, but I want it somewhere else in the page,

Comment: In that case, have a container like literal control or label on the page, or div/span with runat=server, and from code behind, set the text property (webcontrols) or InnerText property (htmlConrol). Like, Label1.Text = "Your Message"; or MyDiv.InnerText = "Div message";

Answer (score 0):

If it is webforms you are using you could just add a panel (`<asp:Panel />`) to your markup and has it disabled/invisible as default. When you have handled your event handler just enable your panel and make it visible. The panel should contain your message.

Comment: that means I should create two panels, first in which I will put all the controls, and second one in which I will write my message, if insertion is successful , I will make visible the message one and make invisible the other one. will it be the correct approach?

Comment: I can't tell you if that is correct, that depends on your requirements. But sound like an idea. You could alse keep the user on the same page as long as the Creation was not successful, and take the user to a new page on success... as you notice there are many opporunities. Also, I would recommend you to be more precise in your question, it is not 100 % clear what you want.